# finding Equation of a Parabola

Tags: calculus

As a preliminary to a question in real analysis where we are later asked to proof issues involving uniform and pointwise convergence, I'm asked to come up with the equation of a parabola fn.

The question reads:

Find the parabolic arcs on $\left[ -\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right]$  s.t. 
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
y_n \left( -\frac{1}{n} \right) &= \frac{1}{n} \\
y_n \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) &= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
\right.
$$
and
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
y_n' \left( -\frac{1}{n} \right) &= -1 \\
y_n' \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) &= 1
\end{align}
\right.
$$

---

I've forgotten so much of the Calc III that I took over two years ago!  Could anyone kindly give me a refresher as to how to arrive at the formula of the parabola?

Comment: I've edited your question to make the equations look better.  Can you check that they look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start from the general quadratic polynomial $ \ y \ = \ a \ x^2 \ + \ b \ x \ + \ c \ . $  One simplification we can make immediately is that, from the stated properties of the arcs, $ \ b \ = \ 0 \ $ , since the functions must have even symmetry. (Note that the derivative of an even function is an odd function, as we see with the derivative values here.)

The derivative is $ \ y' \ = \ 2 \ a \ x \ $ , so we have

$$ a \ \cdot  \ \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \ + \ c \ = \ a \ \cdot \ \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \ + \ c \ = \ \frac{1}{n} \ \ \text{and} $$

$$ 2 \ a \ \cdot \ (\ \pm \frac{1}{n} \ ) \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ . $$

We now have enough information to find the coefficients for the equations of the parabolic arcs as functions of $ \ n \ $ .

Here's a graph showing some members of the sequence:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I realized it was a really number chugging question about 2 minutes after I posted it. But I like your answer -- you've even graphed it!